# Cannot install Skype due to dependency errors; dpkg doesn't install dependencies

Tags: skype, dpkg, dependencies

I'm trying to install the newest Skype version (4.1) on my Linux.

I have downloaded the *skype-ubuntu-lucid_4.1.0.20-1_i386.deb* package from the official Skype site.

I removed all installed versions including the configuration files.

Now when I try to install the downloaded package, I get the following errors:

```
Unpacking skype:i386 (from skype-debian_4.1.0.20-1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:i386:
 skype:i386 depends on libqt4-network (>= 4:4.8.0); however:
  Version of libqt4-network:i386 on system is 4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.2.
 skype:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0); however:
  Version of libqtgui4:i386 on system is 4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.2.
 skype:i386 depends on libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.1.0~2011week13); however:
dpkg: error processing skype:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype:i386
```

Now I thought: I can install the missing dependencies manually, but trying this I got dependency errors again. It seems that dependencies of a package are not downloaded and installed automatically.

Is there a command option for `dpkg` so that missing dependencies are installed automatically?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I've installed **"Linux Mint 12 Lisa"**, which is upgraded to Mint 13.

Comment: Ok Micha, but "Linux Mint" is not an official Ubuntu distribution...but I think, if you are running "Mint 13" the skype package would be for "precise" not for "Lucid".Package for (ubuntu 12.04 multicarch). then you should install it with gdebi.

Comment: Ok, I also tried this but still get: `Unpacking skype:i386 (from skype-ubuntu-precise_4.1.0.20-1_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:i386:
 skype:i386 depends on libqt4-network (>= 4:4.8.0); however:
  Version of libqt4-network:i386 on system is 4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.2.
 skype:i386 depends on libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0); however:
  Version of libqtgui4:i386 on system is 4:4.7.4-0ubuntu8.2.
 skype:i386 depends on libqtwebkit4 (>= 2.2~2011week36); however:
dpkg: error processing skype:i386 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured`

Comment: .. the skype version from within the package manager can be installed without problems, but it is the version _2.*_ which i don't want. ;(

Comment: Please try http://forums.linuxmint.com/. This is not the right forum for Linux Mint (http://askubuntu.com/faq#questions)

Answer (score 12):

Well, as far I as know, dpkg can not resolve dependencies, but because you have **Ubuntu Lucid 10.04** installed , you can use **"Gdebi"** *(gui tool and resolve dependencies)*just doble click in the .deb package.

Another options is... you can run `sudo dpkg -i package.deb` *(it will not a complete install with error dependencies).*
 
After that you just run `sudo apt-get -f install` and the **apt-get** tool will correct the missing dependencies.

Hope this will useful!.

Comment: Ok I will try **Gdebi**. The problem _with sudo apt-get -f install_ is, that it recognizes that there is a broken package (skype) but instead of installing the missing dependencies it wants to delete the broken package.

Comment: Ok Micha, you can try another option and is sudo dpkg -i package.deb and then go to the sypactic tool and in the menu, and use Edit > Fix broken packages.

Comment: I tried, but it's the same like executing _sudo apt-get -f install_ the package manager wants to remove skype instead of install necessary dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **64-Bit Linux**, then this problem is usually due to missing libraries.
Go to Ubuntu Software Center and install ***ia32-libs*** package, and then reinstall Skype.Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: The Software Manager says that **ia32-libs** is already installed.